# Plotting Smoothed Time Series

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, data-visualization

I am trying to follow this tutorial here : https://rc2e.com/timeseriesanalysis ( bottom of the page) and plot a smoothed time series and the original time series on the same plot. I have simulated some data below, smoothed it, and then tried to plot it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(KernSmooth)
library(ggplot2)

a = rnorm(2000,10,10)
    y = ts(a, frequency = 12)

gridsize <- length(y)
bw <- dpill(t, y, gridsize = gridsize)

lp <- locpoly(x = t, y = y, bandwidth = bw, gridsize = gridsize)
smooth <- lp$y

ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = t, y = y)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = t, y = smooth), linetype = 2)
```

However, there seems to be some problem. The first error appears :  `'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list', method "shell" and "quick"`

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Left my laptop at work but can hazard a guess that you should define `data =` in the `geom_line()` calls before the aesthetic? `ggplot` likes to know where x and y are coming from. Is it `bw`?

Comment: thank you for your reply! there seems to be a problem here: > bw <- dpill(t, y, gridsize = gridsize)
Error in locpoly(xcounts, ycounts, drv = 2L, bandwidth = gamseh, range.x = range.x,  : 
  'bandwidth' must be strictly positive

Answer (score 1):

You can fit a smoothed curve to a time series directly in ggplot. Here's an example using `gam` inside `geom_smooth`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
a <- cumsum(rnorm(2000, 0.1, 10))
t <- seq(as.Date("1854-06-01"), by = "1 month", length.out = 2000)

ggplot(data.frame(t, a), aes(t, a)) + 
  geom_point(size = 0.1, color = "orange2", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'gam', formula = y ~ s(x, k = 30, bs = "cs"),
              fill = "orange", color = "orange4", linetype = 2) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! do you know what was wrong with my way of doing it?

Comment: @Noob the method you were using doesn't seem to like being given date-time values on the x axis (also you were using a variable called `t` that doesn't exist). It should work if you define `t` as `t <- seq_along(a)`